# Is it safer to transfer previous page location via GET method rather than HTTP_REFERER?

Tags: php

I want to store the page location the user came from (on my site). I want to do that for this example: say someone sent a comment without being logged in. `"process_comment.php"` will process it and send a `header(location:$_GET['prev_page']);` Of course I'm gonna filter $_GET before sending it.

Should I use a session instead?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is actually exactly the same. Both methods imply that the information is passed in the HTTP query, which can easily be forged. So you can't really trust one method more than the other.

That being said, as long as you don't rely on that information for something really important, you can admit that the referer can be trusted, because it's a little bit more complex to forge than a querystring parameter. At least for the average user.

The best solution, if you need to trust that information for something important, would be to store it on the server, as a session variable for instance. Each page would store its URL, after checking what the previous value was.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `$_SESSION`, there will be trouble if the user has multiple windows/tabs open and does different things at once. There is nothing more annoying than being able to only have window of a site.

You could store the value in a SESSION variable and identify it by a short key. That key goes into the GET string. That way, you can keep your URLs clean, and you don't risk hitting the 1024 byte limit many servers have for GET parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the HTTP_REFERER can be stripped out by some clients.. I seem to remember some Norton Internet security products did that, probably others do too. So it is going to be more reliable for you to set the previous page in a session and use that for redirecting.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use it, session is a safer option. Sending user back from GET or even headers will allow crafty people to possibly abuse any flaws in your code to possibly do nasty things.

The header itself may also be removed by some firewall software.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a problem with using GET in this case. You can't always depend on being able to retrieve the referrer from the browser.